# How to call bootbox.alert() from javascript after button click from C# file

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootbox

I want to call "bootstrap.alert" method which i have written in a JavaScript function myfunction().

Here is the aspx code:-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="temp1.aspx.cs"    Inherits="temp1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <script type="text/javascript">

     function myfunction() {
         bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function () {
         });
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Test" ID="btnTest"     OnClick="btnTest_Click"/>
</form>
<!-- JS dependencies -->
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- bootbox code -->


<script src="Scripts/bootbox.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Csharp code:-

```
public partial class temp1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //What should i write here to call the javascript function "myfunction()" and that bootbox.alert() is executed.
}
}
```

I want to show bootbox alert box upon clicking the button. Please help me to write the code in the button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the attribute onclientClick

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Test" ID="btnTest"     OnClick="btnTest_Click" OnClientClick="myFunction"/>
```

Comment: on doing so, it is not executing the two lines inside the function.  i have written console.write function but No output is shown in the console.

Comment: This is the msdn link . it will explain better.                                                   [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: here bootbox.alert() is defined in bootbox.js file. So can i call the bootbox.alert() from inside the myfunction()?

Comment: Yes. just call tour JS file ref and then your MEthod.
`code`<script src="Scripts/bootbox.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function myfunction() {
         bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function () {
         });
     }
   </script>`

Comment: Thank you @Med.Amine.Touil . It worked. It was the problem of hierarchy. i first linked bootbox.js, then jquery.js, then bootstrap.js, and then wrote thefunction myfunction(). and it worked.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good @Burhan Vakhariya :)). May you please mark my answer as a correct one. Thank you